# Slider handle going outside the horizontal slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make the handle move to where the slider is but it is going outside the slider. Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/endl3ss/gk7fu/3/

CSS

```
body {
    text-align: centre;
 }

.ui-slider-handle, .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-default{
    height: 17px !important;
    width: 20px;
    background: none !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    top: 0 !important;  
    border:0 !important;
    outline: 3px solid black !important;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 17px !important;
    width: 200px !important;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is *by design* and was raised as [**defect #4308**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4308) (closed bug: wontfix), however a workaround was suggested on [jquery-ui slider handle finish position is 100% left - placing it outside the slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290213/jquery-ui-slider-handle-finish-position-is-100-left-placing-it-outside-the-sl) which wraps the *slider* in a padded `<div>` with the padding being half the handle width. Applying this to your code would be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-slider{
    border:none; /* remove border here */
}

.wrapper { /* padded container now has the border */
    width:200px;
    padding:0 10px; /* left+right padding of handle width/2 */
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gk7fu/6/)

Comment: Thanks I also find out that this is a close bug and so I did handle the problem but your solution is much lesser than mine which is great.